# How to show app Statistics from Google Play (Daily uninstalls by device) in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-play-developer-api

In Google Play Developer Console I have app Statistics (Daily uninstalls by device).
But I need to show that statistics in Google Analytics too (for future retrieving by API).
Also I have linked Google Play account with Google Analytics but it isn't showing statistics even next three days after linked.
Acquisition->Google Play Referral Flow tab says: "You may have applied a condition such as a date range, an advance segment or a goal for which there is no data; or there may not be enough data to show results when sampling is in effect"
And Acquisition->Sources->Google Play tab doesn't contain any data.

Maybe I need something else to retrieve that statistics?